# How to query on start of server in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**Start.js:**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', {useNewUrlParser: true}); //to connect with mongodb..not exact code I used but this
```

Now lets say I have stored some data in mongodb....in **Books collection stored in model books**

I call the model and fetch from it:

```
const bookdetails = Books.find({ }).exec()
```

I tried :

```
var respo;
bookdetails.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result) //gives the value stored in bookdetails
    respo = result; 
})
console.log(respo) //...but value not stored in here...it gives undefined
```

But console.log(bookdetails) it gives....**Promise {  }** instead of all the data stored inside book collection. How can I fetch data on start of server....if I'm using through routes or calling api it is working perfectly fine

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Comment: is that the full mongoose code? Did you connect it after setting `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', {useNewUrlParser: true}); `

Comment: Yes I have successfully connected with mongoose...as you can see in my edited question I'm able to fetch the actual data but cannot store in another variable ...please look at my edited query and suggest me. Thank you.:)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a callback that will execute after the promise is resolved or use async/await

```
let bookDetails ;
Books.find()
  .exec(function (err, book) {
  if(err)
    throw new Error(err)
  else
    bookDetails = book
});
```

or

```
const bookdetails = await Books.find({ })
```

Comment: Thank you for you help...I'm trying to set value in bookDetails but it is not setting the value. I cannot try your second step as I don't want to async function to be able to use it. I just want to run it as server starts. Also as I conse.log(book) it is giving me all the vale inside array of object  but unable to set it in bookdetails

Comment: What do you want to do with the data after you fetch it? Maybe I will be able to help you if I knew what you wanted to do

Comment: After fetching the value, based on certain keys I want to send fetched data to another function . But why cannot I set the value inside bookdetails? Could you help me figure out.